# Gitlab installation on CentOS 6 server

Tags: vhosts

I have installed GitLab on CentOS server, external URL http://gitlabname.com. This server IP Address 234.455.33.223. It's shared IP address. it's used to many domains (e.g domain1. Com, domain2. Com). Finally, I hit any domain like domain1. Com,domainx.com it is redirected to http://gitlabname. Com. Why does redirect to http://gitlabname.com

Comment: Please explain `It's shared IP address use to many domain` and also how you did that

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programing related, better asked on serverfault.com, it's a vhost configuration problem